# Recording a win or loss in a game of craps

Tags: python

So I have to create a game of craps that takes into account bets for an assignment. So far, my code works in that the dice rolls are correct and other little tidbits the assignment called for. But now I don't know how to record each game as a win / lose for the player or computer so that the pot can be added to the winner's money.  I realize that my code is half doe, isn't finished, and doesn't run as is, but I just seriously need some help from someone. Please and thank you. Here are more specific directions on my assignment:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kay/courses/i42/hw/labA.html

```
import random

def craps():
    print("Welcome to Sky Masterson's Craps Game")
    handle_commands()

def handle_commands():  # Collection -> Collection (plus interaction)
    """ Display menu to user, accept and process commands
    """

    playerInitial = 500
    compInitial = 500

    MENU = "How much would you like to bet?: " 
    while True:
        bet = float(input(MENU))
        if bet <= playerInitial:
            human_game()           
        elif bet > playerInitial:
            print("Sorry, you can't bet more than you have")

def handle_commands2():


MENU2 = "Would you like to play again? (y or n): "

while True:
    response = input (MENU2)
    if response=="y":
        counter = counter + multipleGames()
    elif response=="n":
        while ( counter < 2000):
            roll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1,6)
            updateCount(roll)
            counter += 1
        print ("Thank you for playing." + "\n" + "\n" + "Distribution of dice rolls: " + "\n")
        return
    else:
        invalid_command(response)



def invalid_command(reponse):
    """print message for invalid menu command.
    """
    print("Sorry; '" + response + "' isn't a valid command. Please try again.")



def play_game():
    """prints shooters roll results
    """
    diceRoll = 0
    roll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
    updateCount(roll)
    diceRoll = diceRoll + 1

    point = 0
    print("The roll is " + str(roll))
    response = (roll)
    if response== 7 or response== 11:
        print("Natural; shooter wins" + "\n" + "Thank you for playing")
        handle_commands2()

    elif response== 2 or response== 3 or response== 12:
        print("Crapped out; shooter loses" + "\n" + "Thank you for playing")
        handle_commands2()
    else:
        print("The point is " + str(roll))
        point = roll
        secondRoll = 0
        handle_commands()

        while (secondRoll !=point) and (secondRoll != 7):
            secondRoll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
            updateCount(secondRoll)
            diceRoll += 1
            print("The roll is " + str(secondRoll))
            handle_commands()
        if secondRoll== point:
            print ("Made the point; shooter wins." + "\n" + "Thank you for playing")
            handle_commands2()
        elif (secondRoll == 7):
            print ("Crapped out; shooter loses." + "\n" + "Thank you for playing")
            handle_commands2()
 return diceRoll


def multipleGames():
    gameCounter = 0
    while (gameCounter <= 2000):
        print("Your game: ")
        gameCounter += play_game()
        print("\n")
        print("Computer's game: ")
        gameCounter += play_game()       
        print( "\n")
    return gameCounter

def updateCount(point):
    count =List[point] + 1
    List[point] = count


List = {2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0,  6:0, 7:0, 8:0,  9:0,  10:0,  11:0,  12:0}

def human_game():
    playerInitial = 500
    compInitial = 500
    while True:
        play_game()
    if 

    playerInitial += bet
    compInitial += bet 
    counter = 0
    counter = counter + multipleGames()
playerInitial -= bet






craps()
for point in List:
    print("%2d" %(point) + ": " + "%3d" %(List[point]) + " " + "(" + ("%2d" %    (int((List[point])/2000*100)))+ "%" + ")" + " " + ("*" *(int((List[point])/2000*100))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use classes:

```
import random

class Human:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Human'
    self.wins = []
    self.losses = []
    self.bets = []
    self.total = 0

class Computer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Computer'
    self.wins = []
    self.losses = []
    self.bets = []
    self.total = 0

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    self.rolls = []
    self.currentPlayer = None

  def roll(self):
    self.rolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  human = Human()
  computer = Computer()
  game = Game()

  game.roll()
  print games.rolls
```

I won't code all of it for you, but using classes will make things *much* simpler.